# How does docker engine communicate to docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I would like to know how a Docker engine communicate with Docker containers.
For example, when we issue a command `docker stop <container-id>`, the docker engine will stop the container with the `<container-id>`.

How does these two processes communicate to each other? Is it through signal or some other mechanism?

I understand that Docker CLI talks to Docker Engine via Unix socket (also TCP binding is also possible). What I am looking for is how the Docker engine communicate with Docker containers.

Comment: `I understand that Docker CLI talks to Docker Engine via Unix socket (also TCP binding is also possible). What I am looking for is how the Docker engine communicate with Docker containers.` I do not understand. In that sense there is no communication. What is communicated? I think https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/ is enough to answer your question? `The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL.`

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk. If you put it in the answer section, I can accept the answer also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/ :

> The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL.